# How to retweet users' tweets in Python (and not their followers' tweets/RTs)

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I am building a bot that will copy and paste tweets from several users (candidates to a presidential election). 
When I run the code, my bot is actually copying **supporters'** tweets and retweets thus creating insane traffic on my page - all I want to copy is what the **candidates themselves** tweet from their account.

Anyone know how to do that?

I thought this:
`if tweetText.startswith('RT @'):
pass`
would solve the RT issue but apparently not...

Here is my code:

```
import twitter, sys, json, csv, time

# this app is being run by cast laboratory..@CASTlaboratory (4003669463)
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret,consumer_key, consumer_secret)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

#Users we are following: Nicolas Dupont-Aignan, Francois Asselineau, Francois Fillon, Philippe Poutou, Jacques Cheminade, Emmanuel Macron, Nathalie Arthaud, Marine le Pen, Benoit Hamon, Jean Lassalle, Jean Luc Melenchon.

u = "38170599, 200659061, 551669623, 374392774, 150201042, 1976143068, 1003575248, 217749896, 14389177, 102722347, 80820758"

print >>sys.stderr, 'Retweeting everything for users="%s"' % (u)
twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=twitter_api.auth)
stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(follow=u)

for tweet in stream:

    tweetText = tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
    print tweetText
    user = tweet['user']['screen_name']

    if tweetText.startswith('RT @'):
        pass

    else:

        print tweetText
        twitter_api.statuses.update(status = tweetText)
        time.sleep(60)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Correcting this shouldn't be too difficult - however, I'm intrigued as to why you are trying to copy the text of these tweets rather than actually retweeting them, as is the function of retweeting itself.

Comment: @asongtoruin Retweeting was my original goal but after a lot of research it seems it is not authorised by Twitter API regulation. The best I found was Tweepy that allows me to retweet up to 20 tweets... If you know something I don't (which you probably do because I'm very new at this), don't hesitate to share :) But otherwise I'm fine with copying and pasting - I am just using this feed as an aggregator for my journalism studies.

Comment: fair enough. If it's for your studies, are you committed to the idea of having it as a twitter account? Do you need it to be maintained "live" or are you okay with the idea of just storing historic tweets?

Comment: Yeah I need it to be a Twitter account and it needs to be live too... We've done scraping tweets into a csv file before (if that's what you wanted to suggest..?) so I need to make it harder for myself :/

Comment: Arguably what you are suggesting is a violation of [Twitter's rules](https://support.twitter.com/articles/18311) - it considers it spamming "if you repeatedly post other people’s account information as your own (bio, Tweets, URL, etc.)", which is what it sounds like you are doing here.

Comment: Well technically the tweet would be preceded by the tweeter's screen name so I wouldn't be taking credit for any of it. But retweeting all the time is also considered spam so....what to do?

Comment: ...don;t do something that violates the terms of use? I am struggling to see the use for what you're trying to do. If it's just to aggregate what accounts say, you should be creating an account that just follows these that you're interested in. If it's aggregating data from the accounts, you should be downloading the information in some way.

Comment: The instructions for the project are to create a Twitter bot with a journalistic purpose. I will be scraping the tweets alongside that for the sake of it but I do need to automatically retweet them. The bot will be disabled at the beginning of May anyway and I will be developing the ethical aspect of bots (spamming, T&Cs etc). It's really just an exercise :)

Comment: I don't think automatic retweets would qualify as a "journalistic purpose" would it? Why not do something more creative with the data - find out who is tweeting the most each day, times of day they're tweeting at, topics they're tweeting about etc

Comment: I definitely agree with you on that but we've done this type of exercise before. The purpose here is enabling users to follow one account (the bot) to know what the candidates are tweeting instead of following 11 accounts - especially if they're worried it means showing endorsement for certain politicians (mainly, Marine le Pen). This is just an exercise that is supposed to show my tutor that I can set up an "easy" bot, even if its usefulness is debatable (all this is discussed in the essay I'm handing in with it). He gave me his approval for it so I'm just trying to meet my deadline now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the tweets to only match those coming from the users you're looking at, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
for tweet in stream:
    tweet_text = tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
    user_id = tweet['user']['id']
    user_name = tweet['user']['screen_name']

    if user_id in u:
        print '@{}: {}'.format(user_name, tweet_text)
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        pass
```

As discussed in the comments, you should not be blanket-reposting tweets from different accounts. If this is something you've been explicitly asked to do in your assignment, maybe you should highlight this in your answer.